# Auto Scaling - How to ensure that the instances run for nearly an hour?

Tags: amazon-ec2

By using multiple autoscaling policies for scale up and scale down can I ensure that my Instances run for nearly an hour ?
How are instances terminated in a Autoscaling group ? **Can I specify instance with the lowest CPU utilization to be terminated** ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'm inferring that your goal here is to keep servers around for as much of a full hour once they've been started up.

One possible approach would be to add a custom metric that report once a minute what your uptime is, and then set a policy to downscale any instances with:

> CPU < x% and uptime > 50 minutes and uptime < 60 minutes